# Sql Insert values in table missing from a known set grouped by date

Tags: mysql, server

Any help how to best tackle this issue please.

To simplify, I have a table consisting of 5 statuses 'A' to 'E'

I have another table with daily amounts of statuses. New records are inserted on a daily basis. When a status is not quantified, it has not been inserted. I need to insert the status and date and set QTy to 0.

```
create table dailyRecords(
  id int,
  status varchar(50),
  Qty int,
  myDate date
  )


  insert into dailyRecords values (1,'a',10,'2016-02-02');
  insert into dailyRecords values (2,'b',10,'2016-02-02');
  insert into dailyRecords values (3,'c',10,'2016-02-02');
  insert into dailyRecords values (4,'a',10,'2016-02-01');
  insert into dailyRecords values (5,'b',10,'2016-02-01');
  insert into dailyRecords values (6,'c',10,'2016-02-01');
  insert into dailyRecords values (7,'d',10,'2016-02-01');
  insert into dailyRecords values (8,'a',10,'2016-01-31');


create table status(
  id int,
  status varchar(50),
  )  

insert into status values (1,'a');
insert into status values (2,'b');
insert into status values (3,'c');
insert into status values (4,'d');
insert into status values (5,'e');
id  status Qty  date
 1,  A      10  2016-02-02
 2,  B      10  2016-02-02
 3,  C      10  2016-02-02
 4,  A      10  2016-02-01
 5,  B      10  2016-02-01
 6,  D      10  2016-02-01
 7,  E      10  2016-02-01
```

to insert the missing statuses for each day as:

```
 8,  D      0  2016-02-02
 9,  E      0  2016-02-02

10,  C      0  2016-02-01
```

Here is a sample code:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b1029/6

I have searched the forum but the added date issue is confusing me.

Any help please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the rows with all dates and statuses using a `cross join`.  Then you can `left join` to get the existing values:

```
select d.date, s.status, coalesce(dr.qty, 0) as qty
from (select distinct date from dailyRecords) d cross join
     (select status from dailyRecords) s left join
     dailyRecords dr
     on dr.date = d.date and dr.status = s.status;
```

If you insert these back into the table, then the first column can be set as an auto-incremented id.

Comment: Hi Gordon. This option works well in my case. I now need to work on this query to work on real tables containing more columns etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by joining the tables together(in the future try posting you tables structure for us to be able to help you better)

```
SELECT s.date,s.status,coalesce(t.Qty,0) FROM(
SELECT status,CURDATE() as date from statusTable) s
LEFT JOIN OtherTable t
ON t.date = s.date and t.status = s.status
```

It seems like you also need to group by the other table results, if so , this is the query you need:

```
SELECT s.date,s.status,coalesce(t.Qty,0) FROM(
SELECT status,CURDATE() as date from statusTable) s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT date,status,count(*) as Qty
           FROM OtherTable
           GROUP BY date,status) t
ON t.date = s.date and t.status = s.status
```

Comment: Tks for your response. It is a way in the right direction.

Comment: Its not in the right direction its the answer.. @NotForFun

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both @sagi and @Gordon.
Here is the full working sql including the insert:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72882/9

```
insert into dailyRecords(mydate,status,qty)
select *
from (
SELECT DISTINCT d.myDate, s.status, COALESCE (dr.Qty, 0) AS qty
FROM         (SELECT DISTINCT myDate
                       FROM          dailyRecords                   
                       ) AS d 
                       cross JOIN
                          (SELECT DISTINCT status
                            FROM          dailyRecords) AS s 
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dailyRecords AS dr ON dr.myDate = d.myDate AND dr.status = s.status 
    ) as b
where b.qty = 0
ORDER BY myDate, status
```